# Multiple ButtonBarView in single view controller in XLPagerTabStrip library

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I have a requirement to show one ButtonBarView in the upper half of screen and second ButtonBarView in the lower half of the screen.
How to implement multiple ButtonBarView in single view controller?
Please help me. This is in the XLPagerTabStrip Library from GitHub found [here](http://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @AhmadF i have tried with single ButtonBarView in single view controller, which works fine

Comment: So, is there a problem anymore? if its not, you might want to delete the question...

Comment: @AhmadF problem is how to implement Multiple ButtonBarView in single view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using a 'toolbar' to present a ButtonBarItem as I have not heard of a ButtonBarView. (I also tried finding it in the interface and  could not)
so if you grab two different toolbars you will be able to have one in the upper half and one in the lower half.
Eg:
[image]
Then you can link all your buttons to your view controller like normal.

Hope I answered your question, Toby :)

Comment: Also if you know how to resize images in SO could you please tell me? (Sorry, I am still kinda learning the basics of it...)

Comment: Hi @Toby, actually this question is regarding to library https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip They have ButtonBarView component to show Tab bar in view controller. I have updated my question. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Hi, I offered an edit towards the question so people will be able to find where it comes from and come up with solutions. If nobody else answers you could read their Usage/Customisation part of the GitHub website. This may provide the answer you are seeking. Sorry I could not help, Toby.